# How autowire can be used in methods using spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring application and now need some suggestions for the below mentioned scenario.

I have a method in a scheduler, and for each time a scheduler runs I want to create a new bean object in the method as shown in the below code for worker object. So how can I achieve this?

```
while(itr.hasNext()){
        Device dev = itr.next();
        connDetails = new ConnectionDetails(dev.getIpaddress(), dev.getPort(), dev.getPassword(), dev.getPassword());

        ScheduledMessage worker = ?;
        worker.set_id(dev.get_id());
        worker.setConnDetails(connDetails);
        executor.execute(worker);
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean like a thread scoped bean?

Comment: you could grab one directly from the bean factory

Answer (score 0):

In your SpringConfig.xml:

```
<!-- Enable the annotation usage (bean injection for instance) -->
<context:annotation-config />
<!-- Message bean (several instances) -->
<bean id="scheduledMessageBean" class="com.myapp.ScheduledMessage" scope="prototype" />
```

In your java class:

```
ScheduledMessage worker = BasicBeanFactory.getInstance().getBean("scheduledMessageBean");
```

You can check there §3.2.1 how to build the BeanFactory for your application (requires Spring Application context): http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.9/reference/beans.html

For instance (not tested example):

```
public class BasicBeanFactory
{
    private static BasicBeanFactory instance = null;

    /** The application context. */
    private ApplicationContext ctx = null;

    protected BasicBeanFactory() {
        // Init spring context
        ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringConfig.xml");
    }

    public Object getBean(String name) throws BeanInstantiationException {
        Object bean = null;
        try {
            bean = ctx.getBean(name);
         } catch (BeansException e) {
            throw new BeanInstantiationException(e);
        }
        return bean;
    }

    public static BasicBeanFactory getInstance() {
        if (instance  == null) {
            instance= new BasicBeanFactory();
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just a correction, no need of 'context:annotation-config' if you never use @Autowire on your classes attributes.

Comment: It says there is no method as getInstance() for BeanFactory class.

Comment: BeanFactory is an interface. You can implement it or use method provided in the spring doc.

Answer (score 0):

Get object from current Spring context that will work well!